# importing gpg key freezes the terminal

Tags: debian, repository, gpg

To install `insync` on my debian , i need to add an external repo . Please, save me the part that external repos can be harmful etc etc. I just need this repo.
The problem is that when I try to import the gpg key, the process freezes.
This is the state of the operation, it's been stuck for half an hour.

```
    ale@debian:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ACCAF35C
    Executing: /tmp/tmp.pgGnNotiOR/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
    keyserver.ubuntu.com
    --recv-keys
    ACCAF35C
```

And nothing more happens. What can I do to solve this hideous issue?
Thank you all in advance

Comment: Why do you want to add a Ubuntu repo to a Debian machine?

Comment: I need to add the insync repo, I'm just following the instructions written on their website (https://www.insynchq.com/downloads)

Comment: Of course, I just can download the deb from their website and install it, as I just did, but I wouldn't have the comfort of updates from the repo. And, btw, it happens also when importing other gpg keys, such as the one for the R-cran repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install `insync` on debian , run the following command:

```
echo "deb http://apt.insynchq.com/debian $(lsb_release -cs) non-free" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get install insync
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. And what about the fact that when importing any gpg key it hangs?

Comment: @Ale i found an answer here  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#gpg_hanged_for_all_keyservers_.28when_trying_to_receive_keys.29

Comment: killed dirmng, didn't solve the proble

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem. Maybe it was a sort of bug in the gpg and dirmng present in the testing repos, so I upgraded them to the version you can found in sid and the key has been correctly imported

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem my downgrading gnupg and gnupg2, as per instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/459480/downgrading-packages-in-debian). Similar solution to commenter Ale, indicating a current problem with testing's version.